# Help identifying this chip

Tags: eeprom

[image: remote power locking kit chip]

Can anyone identify this chip? It came out of a central locking kit fitted to my car. But I didn't get the keyfob with it. From what I can tell it's a Fairchild semiconductor. With the writing on the bottom. The power pins are 2 and 3, which is unusual. Maybe a micro controller?

Comment: How do you know that the power pins are 2 and 3? What other information are you not telling us?

Comment: I traced the power supply lines from the 5v regulator on the pcb to pins 2 and 3